# Staking：How to build and send a staking transaction? can you give me a example?

Tags: transactions, staking

1. How to build and send a staking transaction? What steps and rpc should be used ？
2. which steps is difference between building a balance thansfer ?

Answer (score 1):

I think [staking-payout](https://github.com/canontech/staking-payouts) is a good example for you.

You could start from the [`signAndSendTxs`](https://github.com/canontech/staking-payouts/blob/718192448ffccf36a667355bd0498ecf75c66483/src/services.ts#L397).

Comment: I want to achieve three functions:
1. The one is becoming a nominator and staking my amount;
2. The two is appending the staking my amount;
3. The three is unbounding my staking amount;
Can you give me the example about the ? I do not know how to write and use which rpc,

Comment: How to build the payload?